# Does the GC know about the IIS app pool memory limit?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, memory, garbage-collection

I have a .NET C# website in IIS.

If the assigned app pool doesn't have a memory limit, the app memory usage seems to grow until there is maybe 1GB of RAM left, then there is seemingly a garbage collection event and the memory usage goes back down dramatically.  Rinse and repeat.

However, if I set a `Private Memory Limit (KB)` in the app pool to a specific (pretty low, but double of what app uses initially) value, the app will grow in memory usage and then the app pool will recycle.

1. Is the garbage collector aware of the IIS app pool limit?
2. If not, is there a way to notify the garbage collector that there is one?

[image]

Comment: How long does it take for your process to leave only 1GB for the whole system?

Comment: @RodrigoVedovato  About an hour.  It's a very busy website.

Comment: From what this article is saying http://www.bursky.net/index.php/2013/03/managing-iis-server-memory-usage/ 
"When you apply this setting and any of the worker processes hits this limit, a new worker process for the same pool is created that will take over the processing of the requests. Once this initiation is finished, the original worker process is stopped."